# Horizontally Centering Div in Div is not working

Tags: html, css

I"m trying to center a div within a div. At first, I thought I try to do horizontal centering but that's not working. I looked at this post for horizontal centering [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvLgrd. Here is the styling part of the code that matters

```
#homepage {
  position: relative;
}
#homepage canvas, #console {
  position: absolute;
}
#console {
  background: rgb(224,168,227);
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

For some reason, the console div does not center inside of homepage div. I'm kinda confused.

Also, I was looking up how to center both vertically and horizontally. This website https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ recommends to use

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

I tried it out and had

```
#homepage {
  position: relative;
}
#homepage canvas, #console {
  position: absolute;
}
#console {
  background: rgb(224,168,227);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

But it only centered horizontally. I was also confused on what it was doing? I'm not understand percents well. So if you have `top: 50%` that means "you sets the top edge position in 50% of #homepage". I don't get it. Also for `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`, wouldn't that mean that you translate to the negative numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Your relative div doesn't have a height so it's inherited the height of the #console div.

If you remove the relative position from the `#homepage` your div will center.

```css
#homepage canvas, #console {
  position: absolute;
}
#console {
  background: rgb(224,168,227);
  width: 75%;
  height: 60px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="homepage">
    <canvas id="faces_bkgd"></canvas>
    <div id="console">
      <div id="name">
        <a href="./index.html">Jessica Gu</a>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <div id="menu">
        </div>
        <div id="information">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I thought I needed the relative for #homepage though? I read that absolute only positions itself according to the nearest position element that is not static (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) . If you get rid of relative, then homepage has a position of static

Comment: This is true, but your `#homepage` doesn't have a height attached. So is inheriting the height from the div you are trying to center. in which case the `#console` div is always going to be vertically centered within the `#homepage`

Comment: how is #homepage inheriting the height from #console (the div you are trying to center)? I thought the parent of #homepage is body?

Comment: it is the parent of #homepage. A div doesn't have a height of 100% of the parent. The height of a div is relative to it's contents.

Comment: I thought parent was the element that you were enclosed in? So console is inside of homepage, who is inside of body

Comment: the parent is the wrapping element.

Answer (score 2):

You can center `#console` vertically and horizontally by removing the `position: absolute;` on the canvas:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoNMPX)

```
#homepage {
  position: relative;
}    
#console {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(224,168,227);
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
   top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Recommended reading: [Center Anything with CSS](http://www.studiomashbo.com/blog/article/center-anything-with-css)

Comment: Can you explain how `translate(-50%, -50%)` works? I really don't get working with percents (esp negative)

Comment: I would recommend this article: http://www.studiomashbo.com/blog/article/center-anything-with-css

Comment: it was a pretty cool article. But i don't get the logic behind positioning an element from top by 50% and then negative margin it back by half it's own height. How does that make something centered? So if i have a container that is 70x70 and a inside_box that is 30x30 (want to center inside_box in container), inside_box has to be 20 away from container. So top:50% will put inside_box down at 45. Then translate(-50%,-50%) will push you up by 15 right? Therefore inside_box is 30 away from container

Comment: also, why do they use translate3D? why not use translate(..., ...)? Cause before they were using translateY(). Translate( , ) allows you to set x and y both simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

Centering it horizontally is not that hard, simply remove the position absolute from the console element, and the auto will work.

```
#homepage {
  position: relative;
}
#homepage canvas {
  position: absolute;
}
#console {
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(224,168,227);
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Centering the element vertically is harder in case the height of each element is not exact. I would remodel the entire css to use flexbox, since it gives you more control over element positioning: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

In order to use percentage as your unit, you need to make the outer div have max width of 100% or 100vh then your original code will

```css
body{
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 8%);
    min-width: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.box{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

or you could switch to using a different unit like px, then you can just do the same thing but this time setting a max width and height using pixels